# Does anyone know why this code just won't work

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

To me it makes sense, then again I'm nowhere near an expert. So I'm working on a project for my first programming course and I've been stuck on this question all day, I have probably done 5 hours of cumulative research trying to figure out how this is even possible.

Basically I need to shuffle these 'cards' for a memory game and I can't figure out why it's not working. The program runs fine but none of the images change. I put the `cout` in there just to make sure that the value was changing each time, I just don't know why it won't swap with those values. I tried the shuffle and random_shuffle thing but I most likely did not do it right, if someone could show me what it has to look like with my code I would be ever so grateful. I'm just so puzzled as to why it won't work. If someone could provide a working example explaining as to where I went wrong that would be amazing.

```
void shuffle(int board[][NCOLS]) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int randomX = dis(gen);
        swap(board[randomX][randomX], board[randomX][randomX]);
        cout << "num = " << randomX << endl;
    }

}
```

I'm right in calling the function by using `shuffle(board);` correct? It's just weird because there's already a built in function called shuffle correct?

Comment: What do you expect `swap(board[randomX][randomX], board[randomX][randomX]);` to do?

Comment: Once you get this code working, you should know that it still isn't a perfect shuffle. See [Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: i expected swap(board[randomX][randomX],board[randomX][randomX]); to fill with random values, swap them, and do that 20 times to shuffle the 'cards'

Comment: you are trying to swap an element in your array with itself, so nothing happens in the end(swap is performed but no visible effect)

Comment: omg how did i not see that...i'm not quite sure how this uniform_int_distribution thing works though, is it possible that i could just make another random number say randomY and just use that? or would randomX and randomY be the same?

Comment: The 'uniform_int_distribution' takes values from the random number generator and maps them to the range (you gave [1,6]) such that each has an equal (uniform) probability of occurring.

Comment: @Nick Every time you call `dis(gen)` you get a random number between 1 and 6 inclusive.

Comment: Ok so I know this looks really stupid and unclean but I'm not sure why this wouldn't work: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:5011      A lot of the times the program crashes as well which I don't seem to get. I really just need to get this done, there has to be a better way

Comment: Since your board appears to be 2 dimensional, I believe you need 4 random numbers for each swap. I.e, swap(board[randomX1][randomY1],board[randomX2][randomY2]). That won't help with your crashes, though.

Comment: Unless swap () dereferences the variables, you are probably passing them by value and not reference - therefore, it is modifying a copy of the value, not the actual value.

Comment: You should change the title of the question to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason `swap(board[randomX][randomX], board[randomX][randomX]);` does nothing is that you are trying to exchange a board diagonal element with itself.  This leads to an unchanged board.

First of all, you need to select two random elements, you need to select random variables for the line and the column of each element from your array, or, as you do in your example, you will only select elements in the diagonal of the matrix (these are the ones with equal line and column ids) so:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20;) {
    int randXA = dis(gen), // I'll suppose this does the right work
        randYA = dis(gen),
        randXB = dis(gen),
        randXB = dis(gen);

    if (randXA != randXB || randYA != randYB) { 
        /* we have two distinct elements. */
        swap(board[randXA][randYA], board[randXB][randYB]);
        /* we need to increment i conditionally or we can 
         * finish with less than 20 swaps. */
        i++;
    } /* if */
} /* for */
```

be careful, as it is supposed that `dis(gen);` is generating a valid number.  If matrix is not square, you'll have to adjust as `randX<A,B>` and `randY<A,B>` have different ranges (one goes `0..MAXX-1` and other `0..MAXY-1`.  In that case, you'll have to use:

```
int randXA = rand() % MAXX,
    randXB = rand() % MAXX,
    randYA = rand() % MAXY,
    randYB = rand() % MAXY;
```